# Jquery serialize 2 arrays?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Within my page I have a normal form and I serialize that and submit it via AJAX to a back php page to be processed.

On a different tab within the same page, I have two tables that users can add, edit or delete entries from. The updates from this are saved into two arrays one for each table. These arrays are not sent back with the initial form submission.

Once the form submission has completed and is successful, I want to pass these two arrays back for processing.  Ideally I need them going back separately so I can loop through each one individually.

Can that be done. For simplicity the arrays are arrayOne and arrayTwo.
The contain data similar to :

```
['add;1234;533445;23421','edit;5421;530105;66521', 'del;5512;542165;98701']
```

Is there anyone with one AJAX command I can send two unique arrays and if there is how do I access them in php ?

Thanks

Comment: Just add them as `data`  to `$.ajax` inside an object with different keys, it should be trivial

Comment: thanks... how do you do that ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tkgfnk3w/

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it :)